# Redefining "def" in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there anyway to define a new macro under the name `def` in Clojure? I `defmacro`ed a new one after trying to `:refer-clojure :exclude` the original, but it used the built-in definition anyway.

I was trying to enable Scheme-style function definitions (`(def (f x y) ...)` as `(defn f [x y] ...)`) using the following code.

```
(defmacro def
  [ id & others ]
    (if (list? id)
        `(defn ~(first id) [~@(rest id)] ~@others)
        `(def ~id ~@others)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`def` is not a macro, it is a special form. It interns a symbol into current namespace. You cannot redefine special forms, but even if you could, how would you get same behavior?

The most straightforward way is to write `define` macro on base of `def` and `defn`. If you want to use `def` word, you can write a wrapper `replace-my-def-with-normal-def` around all the module, i.e.

```
(replace-my-def-with-normal-def

   (def x 0)
   (def y (inc x))
   (def z (inc y))
   (def (my-func a b) (println a b))

)
```

but I'm not sure it won't break other definitions, which depend on `def` (for example, `defn`).

Comment: You cannot redefine special forms.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a macro with the name of a special form (like if), but it won't help you. Special forms are evaluated before macros, therefore if you have a macro and a special form of same name the special form will always be used. More information here `http://clojure.org/evaluation`.